# SQL : GROUP and MAX multiple columns

Tags: sql, max, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I am a SQL beginner, can anyone please help me about a SQL query?

my table looks like below

```
PatientID   Date        Time    Temperature
1           1/10/2020   9:15    36.2
1           1/10/2020   20:00   36.5
1           2/10/2020   8:15    36.1
1           2/10/2020   18:20   36.3
2           1/10/2020   9:15    36.7
2           1/10/2020   20:00   37.5
2           2/10/2020   8:15    37.1
2           2/10/2020   18:20   37.6
3           1/10/2020   8:15    36.2
3           2/10/2020   18:20   36.3
```

How can I get each patient everyday's max temperature:

```
PatientID   Date        Temperature
1           1/10/2020   36.5
1           2/10/2020   36.3
2           1/10/2020   37.5
2           2/10/2020   37.6
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Comment: Are you really storing the data and time in two separate columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this dataset, simple aggregation seems sufficient:

```
select patientid, date, max(temperature) temperature
from mytable
group by patientid, date
```

On the other hand, if there are other columns that you want to display on the row that has the maximum daily temperature, then it is different. You need some filtering; one option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, 
        rank() over(partition by patientid, date order by temperature desc)
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
```